# Mouse move in a container with overflow JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a container of `200px` that have a container itself with `400px height`, I have a tracking mouse object that moves with it on `mousemove` event

when I'm moving the mouse in the not overflowed part, everything is fine, but when I move the scroll down the object do not track the mouse anymore

```js
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
  $("#image").css({
    left: e.pageX,
    top: e.pageY
  });
});
```

```css
#image {
  position: absolute;
}

.container {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.image-container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-container">
    &nbsp;
    <img id="image" src="http://images.pictureshunt.com/pics/m/mouse-8557.JPG" />
  </div>
</div>
```

There is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfLAh/6310/) link here too.

Comment: because the element is positioned inside of the scrollable element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're not taking account of the `scrollTop` property of `.container` when positioning the cursor element. Try this:

```
let container = $('.container'); //<-- get container
$(document).mousemove(e => {
    $("#image").css({
        left: e.pageX,
        top: e.pageY + container[0].scrollTop //<-- add scroll top too
    });
});
```

In the interests of efficiency, it would also be good to cache the reference to `#image` once rather than grab it afresh every time the event fires.

```
let
container = $('.container'),
image = $('#image')
;
$(document).mousemove(e => {
    image.css({ ...
```